# Webpack 4 - background images in css not showing

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

Hoping someone can help. Don't have a lot of experience with Webpack (this is my first attempt).
But I can't get it to compile when I use a background-image in my css. I have looked around for ages and can't get other peoples suggestions to work. Would anyone be able to help?

My set up looks like

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJSPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
    entry: {
        app: "./js/app.js",
        editor: "./js/editor.js"
        // vendor: ["slick-carousel"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./js/[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: ["css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "resolve-url-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|css)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "url-loader",
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "[name].[ext]",
                            outputPath: "fonts/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
            // {
            //     test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            //     use: ["url-loader", "file-loader"]
            // }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("/css/[name].css"),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            proxy: "localhost:8888/onscale",
            port: 3000,
            files: ["**/*.php"],
            browser: [
                "google chrome"
                // "firefox",
                // "firefox developer edition",
                // "safari"
            ],
            // ghostMode: {
            //     clicks: false,
            //     location: false,
            //     forms: false,
            //     scroll: false
            // },
            injectChanges: true,
            logFileChanges: true,
            logLevel: "debug",
            logPrefix: "wepback",
            notify: true,
            reloadDelay: 0
        })
    ]
};

//If true JS and CSS files will be minified
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    config.plugins.push(new UglifyJSPlugin(), new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin());
}

module.exports = config;
```

and my css is 
`background-image: url("../../assets/img/misc/wave.png");`

I keep getting the message

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/img/misc/wave.png'

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read this section https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#problems-with-url from the sass-loader documentation ?

Comment: I tried to implement what it said but now I get an error saying `Can't resolve 'resolve-url-loader'`. No idea what's going on.

Comment: Have you installed it first? `npm install resolve-url-loader`

Comment: Yeah it's in my package.json. I tried placing it like this.
`{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        "resolve-url-loader",
                        "css-loader",
                        "postcss-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                })
            }`

Comment: It gave me this error `ERROR in ./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./sass/editor.scss
Module build failed: Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error
  file:///Users/fraser/sites/wordpress/onscale/wp-content/themes/OnScale_Dot_Com/sass/editor.scss:1:1: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
  You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser`

Comment: `{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        "css-loader",
                        "resolve-url-loader",
                        "postcss-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                })
            }`

Still no luck with =\